# force landscape Phonegap CLI with phonegap app for testing. android/ios

Tags: cordova, orientation, phonegap-cli

I would like to know if its possible to force landscape mode when using phonegap cli and testing on device with the phonegap app.

I have tried adding:

to the config file with no luck.

What is the best way to handle this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a limitation on the phonegap developer app, there are certain things you can't test as if it was a real app.
See the [issue open](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/373) about it.

Phonegap developer app is just for doing a quick preview of your app, if you really want to test how your app really works you should run your app installing it on the device.

I think the command to do it is `phonegap run android --device`, if not, I think cordova command should work too `cordova run android --device`